# Servlet context alternative

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war

I have a tomcat application that uses Ehcache. The way I initialize Ehcache is during the webapp startup implementing the ServletContextListener  contextInitialized method and storing a reference to the cache in the ServletContext. I want to also package the web app as a jar. What are my alternative to initializing and storing the ehcache so that is it available in both jar and war contexts.

Comment: How do you package a *webapp* as a jar? Or are you talking about a runnable jar with an embedded servlet container? If so, it's still a webapp with a `ServletContext`.

Comment: I am using maven-jar-plugin to package as a jar. I am not using any embedded server.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, I deleted my answer.

Comment: @pup784 If you're not running a web server, then it's not a [*web app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application), hence my confusion about your statement *"I want to also package the **web app** as a jar"*.

Comment: @Andreas - let me try to put it in a different way. I need to package my code both as war and a jar. When i package as jar i no longer have a ServletContext and therefore my cache does not initialize correctly.

Comment: So your code is a *library*, that can be used by any kind of app, not just a web app. In that case, a singleton class stored in a static field is likely your best option.